# Switching off subdomains in phpfastcache

Tags: phpfastcache

I'm using **phpfastcache** with files strategy. I'm caching sql queries.
As I see phpfastcache creates folders with subdomain name (ex. `www.domain.pl`).

I have admin panel in `admin.domain.pl` which calls `api.domain.pl`.

Problem is that when I, for example, want to clear cache from admin panel it clears `api.domain.pl` directory - not `www.domain.pl`.
Can I turn off subdomains in phpfastcache? I don't see such option.

Edit:
I found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33848394/979911

Answer (score 0):

Accordinglly to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33848394/979911
`phpFastCache::setup('securityKey', 'phpfastcache');` is responsible for directory name

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late on this, but a quick heads up on the securityKey:

In your example you tend to mutualize your website cache and admin cache.

This could to potential security issues as the cache directory are not longer compartmentalized.

I warmly advise you to setup two different security key and call them from your admin panel.